# Skeleton framework spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to float my navigation to the right of its current position around 200px more, there is room but it wont move over.

You can view the live code at http://www.xronn.co.uk/hosting

and here is an image to explain my issue a little more

[image]

purple lines the 960px width of the site
blue line shows the space free for the navigation to go
and the red arrows of course shows which direction i want the navigation to go in (the right)

Anyone got any clue why when I push to more to the right, the list starts to sit under each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the html mark-up to look like that:

```
<div class="nine columns">..logo</div>
<div class="seven columns">..navigation</div>
```

this will require no further adjustment and will keep it responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give `<div class="seven columns" style="float: right;">` the holder, it moves to the right.

I used firebug, but you have to test it.

Comment: ah, I see you beat me to it :(